# StreamTokenizer infinite input problem from console

Tags: java

I am beginner in Java, so during my learning another topic as StreamTokenizer, I faced some kind of intresting problem. And I didn't found any close solutions or hints in the Internet.

So, basically, almost every educational source give us an example like this:

```
import java.io.*;

public class pr_23 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        StreamTokenizer st = new StreamTokenizer(br);
        
        while (st.nextToken() != st.TT_EOF)
            if (st.ttype == st.TT_NUMBER)
                System.out.print(st.nval + " "); // not infinite cycle
        
        br.close();
    }
}
```

And it works well. But if I include in the cycle some other operators with st.nval, like double b = st.nval and exclude this System.out.print() code, compiler cant determine the end of the Stream in this case anymore, so it starts infinite reading. I wanted StreamTokenizer gave numbers to my ArrayList, but magically it cant see the end of Stream in this case with similar cycle. What's intresting it does work correctly if I use FileInputStream instead of InputStreamReader. But I need to get input from the console, not from a file. Also, using FIS in Tokenizer is deprecated. So here's similar code, but it doesnt work properly:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class pr_23 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        StreamTokenizer st = new StreamTokenizer(br);
    
        ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>();
        
        while (st.nextToken() != st.TT_EOF) {
            a.add((int)st.nval);   // infinite cycle
        }
        System.out.print(a);
        
        br.close();
    }
}
```

P.S. input is meant to be only int numbers for simplicity

Comment: *"And it works well."* ... really? Then how do you stop it in a way which doesn't work for the second example?

Comment: I don't know, but every source gives similar examples, and what I cant figure out, why in the first case it does work propely, and compiler doesnt read infinitely, but in the second case within adding another operations and similar code it starts infinite reading. I cannot see the problem with logic here, but may be this is peculiarity of console input.

Comment: I hate these book examples that fail to put a close in a finally (or better yet use a try with resources statement).. it just teaches people bad habits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please understand that your loop is repeating until the input reaches to the EOF. And, your latter code does not output anything before your loop would exit. So, if you want to see your output with the latter code, you must close your standard input stream first. To close standard input, you should send EOF code from keyboard. On Linux and macos, you can close standard input with Ctrl-D, and on Windows, it is Ctrl-Z.

Comment: Thank you! That really explains a lot. But is there no way to accomplish this with code instructions instead of shortcuts ?

Comment: Ctrl-D is not a shortcut, but it is bare ascii code 0x04.  7bit ascii code system, 0x00 ~ 0x1F are called "control code" which controls data communication. For example, your "new line" characters are 0x0d or 0x0d 0x0a, and they are, Ctrl-J (10th alphabet) for 0x0a and Ctrl-M (13th alphabet) of 0xd. In "text terminal" system, keyboards "Ctrl" button are for this purpose. Using Ctrl for shortcut was much modern days invention.  Command Prompt and Unix Shells are used to be used on the text terminal and keyboards are treated like that. ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character

Comment: Historically, unix systems are using 0x04 as a mark of the end of the text file. DOS and its ancesters are unable to use it for their reasons, they chose to use 0x1a (Ctrl-Z) as EOF mark. In those days Operating Systems cannot detetmine real file length so they decided to terminate processing when they reached to the EOF mark.

Answer (score -1):

The source of your problem is using `System.in`.

Try reading from a file:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class pr_23 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("myfile.txt"));
        StreamTokenizer st = new StreamTokenizer(br);
    
        ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>();
        
        while (st.nextToken() != st.TT_EOF) {
            a.add((int)st.nval);   // infinite cycle
        }
        System.out.print(a);
        
        br.close();
    }
}
```

The problem is that you won't get an EOF in a System.in if you run it interactively. Though you would get it if you run it like this:

```
java pr_23  < myfile.txt
```

By the way a better way to write this without the dangling close() would be:

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class pr_23 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        // using try this way will close br automagically
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("myfile.txt"))) { 

           StreamTokenizer st = new StreamTokenizer(br);
    
           ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>();
        
           while (st.nextToken() != st.TT_EOF) {
              a.add((int)st.nval);   // infinite cycle
           }
           System.out.print(a);
        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help and your answer! Unfortunately, I dont have enough reputation to make "+1" to your reply. But if I understood this correct, this is quite difficult to input interactively from console using StreamTokenizer ?

Comment: for redirection, you just need to write filename, no need to "cat" it.

Comment: ok.. got rid of the cat

Comment: @Ogurcius it's not difficult to input an end of file signal